# Stationarity of $\ y_t = c_1 +c_2t +u_t$

Tags: time-series, self-study, stationarity

How can I determine if

$\ y_t = c_1 +c_2t +u_t$

is stationary?

$\ c_1$ and $\ c_2 $ are known constants and $\ u_t $ is a white noise process with variance $\sigma^2 $.

I do not understand the role of the t.

Am I right to describe this as a trend stationary process?

How can I show the mean of the moving average?

Comment: Hint: compute the expected value of $y_t$. If a time series is stationary, its marginal distribution, and specifically its expected value, must not vary with $t$.

Comment: It is not stationary because the mean increases with time. If you remove the trend you will have an approximate white nose (stationary) proess.

Comment: Can you show me each step: how to exactly do it? many thanks

Comment: Don't I have to detrend the series first by substracting c_2t?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expected value of $\ y_ t$ = $\ c_1 + c_2 * t $

given that $\ E(u_t) = 0 $

It is not stationary, since the expected value varies with t.